# Use data from js library internal cache

Tags: javascript, jquery, caching, calendar, fullcalendar

I use fullcalendar.io.

I see on official site documentation:

> > lazyFetching
>
> Determines when event fetching should occur.
>
> Boolean, default: true When set to true (the default), the calendar
>   will only fetch events when it absolutely needs to, minimizing AJAX
>   calls. For example, say your calendar starts out in month view, in
>   February. FullCalendar will fetch events for the entire month of
>   February and store them in its internal cache. Then, say the user
>   switches to week view and begins browsing the weeks in February. The
>   calendar will avoid fetching events because it already has this
>   information stored.
>
> When set to false, the calendar will fetch events any time the view is
>   switched, or any time the current date changes (for example, as a
>   result of the user clicking prev/next).

Now I want to know how I can use internal cache to use that data for other things at web page (etc. draw graph and similar)

I also can select data for month I need to why to do that when I already have selected in library cache?

But how I can use it? Where to find it?

Answer (score 1):

The internal events of the fullCalendar can be accessed via the property clientEvents.  ClientEvents returns an array of event objects structured like the JSON event feed except that any dates supplied as strings have been converted to instances of the moment.js object.  You can loop through this array and operate on each event in any manner you please.  Here is an example code fragment from some code I recently implemented showing the syntax to refer to the array:

$('#calendar').fullCalendar('clientEvents');